# Howto update XML with groovy's XML Slurper?

Tags: xml, groovy

I read the Groovy Codehaus article about [Updating XML with XmlSlurper](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Updating+XML+with+XmlSlurper), this leads me to the following question. Consider we have a input XML structured as the upcoming:

```
<customer>
  <address>
    <street />
    <city />
    <postalcode />
  </address>
</customer>
```

Is it possible to change the XML without knowing its concrete structure? Concrete: We have a reference to the `address` Node and want to multiply it 3 times without knowing any details?

```
address.multiply(3)
```

The output should look like this:

```
<customer>
  <address>
    <street />
    <city />
    <postalcode />
  </address>
  <address>
    <street />
    <city />
    <postalcode />
  </address>
  <address>
    <street />
    <city />
    <postalcode />
  </address>
</customer>
```

This could be possible with `appendNode` but I'm missing a clone method for nodes in groovy. Is there any solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The only way I can think of currently for cloning nodes is to serialize them to text, and parse them back in as new bits of xml

Like so:

```
import groovy.xml.StreamingMarkupBuilder
import groovy.xml.XmlUtil

def xml = """
<customer>
  <address>
    <street />
    <city />
    <postalcode />
  </address>
</customer>
"""

def root = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )
2.times {
  String addressXml = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bindNode( root.address )
  clonedAddress = new XmlSlurper().parseText( addressXml )
  root.appendNode( clonedAddress )
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( root )
```

Which prints out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customer>
  <address>
    <street/>
    <city/>
    <postalcode/>
  </address>
  <address>
    <street/>
    <city/>
    <postalcode/>
  </address>
  <address>
    <street/>
    <city/>
    <postalcode/>
  </address>
</customer>
```

There's probably a neater way of doing this...but at the moment, my mind is a blank...

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot. If you ever find a neater way of doing this: Please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

`GPathResult.replaceBody()`  works for me.  Example:

http://www.javamonamour.org/2011/11/groovy-modifying-xml-with-xmlslurper.html